# Div auto generated with Xampp

Tags: html, xampp

I have a simple website with the following structure `body > main > p > 'Hi'`. But it seems that there is an additional div with id `user-css` thats auto generated. What is the cause of this? I am using XAMPP.

```
<body>
    <main>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </main>

    <div id="user-css"><style>#header-container {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .end_space {
        min-height: 500px !important;
    }

    #notebook-container {
        border-radius: 7px !important;
    }</style></div>
</body>
```

Edit: This is my html

```
<body>
    <main>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not auto generated you have placed the div check it

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </main>

 <!--here is the div-->   <div id="user-css"><!--here--><style>#header-container {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .end_space {
        min-height: 500px !important;
    }

    #notebook-container {
        border-radius: 7px !important;
    }</style></div>
</body>
```

between comments see remove it from there and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I never created a div with id user-css. I don't have a div tag for that matter in the html yet there is one.

Comment: the above code is not what you have typed?

Comment: No it appears afterwards which is strange. I'm not sure whats causing this.

Comment: try to put head tag before body tag

Comment: I have nothing it. Could this be the issue?

Comment: If not resolved then try WAMP server. befor trying so uninstall XAMP. Other then this I couldn't find any solution sorry.

Comment: not sure but i found it missing so asked to do so. i could have tried but i use ubuntu so i use LAMP other then this i can't use any server here

Comment: WAMP is for windows so try once here is a link to it. https://wampserver.en.softonic.com/download

Comment: Alright ty anyways!

Comment: Sorry for disappointing, hope you will get solution

Comment: No problem! its a minor issue I'll eventually fix.

Comment: Ok, hope you will find it ✌️✌️